# IE6 and IE7 Sometimes Have A jQuery Bug With 'nodeName' is null or not an object

Tags: jquery, nodename

I'm having a problem where a jQuery setting against an .html() property on a selected element is returning the error 'nodeName' is null or not an object. This only occurs on IE6 and IE7, but not FF2, FF3, Opera (latest Nov 12,2008) or Safari (again, latest).

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the problem. The example looks like this:

$('#section #detail .data').html(data);

...where data is HTML returned from an AJAX call, and this bug only occurs on IE6 and IE7 on the second attempt AJAX call, not the first. It's inexplicable. The error returned is:

```
'nodeName' is null or not an object
```

The fix is to simply clear the variable first before setting:

$('#section #detail .data').html('');
$('#section #detail .data').html(data);

And then IE6 and IE7 started working again with it.

BTW, I had to install Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition to get a debugger working in IE7. That info is [here](http://www.berniecode.com/blog/2007/03/08/how-to-debug-javascript-with-visual-web-developer-express/).

Comment: there is no need to do a selector with two id's. Its slower than going direct to source

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like a bug in JQuery. The exception is thrown at line 605 in 1.5.1:

```
nodeName: function( elem, name ) {
    return elem.nodeName && elem.nodeName.toUpperCase() === name.toUpperCase();
},
```

The function returns true if the nodeName of object `elem` is identical to the String `name`. If not, or if there is no nodeName at `elem`, we return false. However, `elem` is not tested before it is used. So if `elem` is null, the invocation of its `.nodeName` member throws a null pointer exception.

A simple fix is to include `elem` at the beginning of the short-circuit **AND** clause:

```
return elem && elem.nodeName && elem.nodeName.toUpperCase()...
```

Now if `elem` is null, the function will return false at the first test in the clause and never try to invoke `elem.nodeName`, thus avoiding the NPE.

I didn't check them all (it's used a lot), but in many cases where this function is used, `elem` **is** tested before the function call. But not in all cases, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was happening on IE when I was trying to select an element that did not existed. I was trying to get its index amongst its siblings which was returned as -1. Then I tried showing this element by getting it by index from its parent.It resulted in this error.

Thus, I put a check whether the index is not equal to -1. This solved the issue for me.

Comment: Me too, just tried to get an ID that didn't exist in the document and got this error

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's connected, but we've had what sounds like a similar issue where the DOM doesn't have the children/text of a element that we know exist (because we see them rendered on the screen!)

Selecting something else, then selecting the elememt again seemed to fix the issue - suddenly, the children appear. So what happens if you select you element, select something else, select your element again?

Comment: Thanks Paul. You caught me before I could post the answer. I had the question and the answer in my head already before posting, but it took me a second to post the answer. However, what you state is interesting because that's sort of what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any idea what kinds of nodes you might be running up against?  Or, are you running in IE quirks mode?  There might be some kinds of nodes such as #text that don't show up correctly in the DOM in quirks mode.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```